# Conditional styling in .tmux.conf based on session_name

Tags: tmux

I am trying to set the color of my status bar based on the tmux session name - if the name is "ssh", make it green, else blue. I have this snippet in my .tmux.conf

```
# Status bar
%if "#{==:#{session_name},ssh}"
  set -g status-style bg=darkgreen,fg=black
  setw -g window-status-current-style bg=green
%else
  set -g status-style bg=blue
  setw -g window-status-current-style bg=brightcyan
%endif
```

When I first connect to a new session, the status bar is blue. However, if I reload the conf file using `source .tmux.conf`, it correctly changes to green.

This suggest that the session_name might not be available during the first load. How can I set the colors in .tmux.conf so I don't have to manually source it everytime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this via a tmux hook:

```
set-hook -g after-new-session 'run-shell "
  if [ #{==:#{session_name},ssh} ]; then
    tmux set  -g status-style bg=darkgreen,fg=black;
    tmux setw -g window-status-current-style bg=green;
  else
    tmux set  -g status-style bg=blue,fg=black;
    tmux setw -g window-status-current-style bg=brightcyan;
  fi
"'
```

Comment: `if-shell -F` would probably be a tiny bit better than `run-shell` :)